# How can i convert a php page into .doc file with php

Tags: php, ms-word

Recently i worked in a project. On this project I need convert page into a Microsoft word document (.doc file) and offer the document for download, all using PHP. But I can't solve this problem.

Please help me. Thank You very much, Arif

Answer (score 3):

This is not easy to solve.

First off, if you want to write *real* word documents, you will have to do on Windows. You can use [COM](http://us.php.net/com) to talk to Word and this is how you manage to get good results. I've tried all the unix/linux based solutions and the results were not so great.

Otherwise, I'd suggest you write RTF -- which is just as good. And in the end, you can call the .rtf-file, .doc and no one will notice it. RTF has a couple limitations (formatting), but on the flipside -- it's all ASCII and [the RTF standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277.aspx) is pretty comprehensive and well documented.

There's a class which does it pretty nicely -- [phpLiveDocx](http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/brief-introduction-to-phplivedocx/) (this is a great introduction). And this class also claims to write PDF and DOC -- but I haven't tried those yet. I use another solution for PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the RTF format instead of the .doc - it's much simpler to write to, and all text editors understand it. Similar recommendation for .csv when you want to output an Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the answer you seek, but still interesting to note, there is a open source word processor out there called abiword that has a CLI (Command Line Interface). You can use it to easily convert between document formats. I know that at least one website uses it to convert text files into various formats.

It is actively getting developed and could easily be used as a 3de party black box solution to converting documents server side.

Here is a blog from one of the developers on how to integrate it with PHP

[Server-Side AbiWord](http://www.advogato.org/person/msevior/diary.html?start=65)

[abiword home page](http://www.abisource.com/)